# Select every list elements using field checkbox, not only - on example 50

Tags: lightning, community, case, list, checkbox

Does Salesforce make it possible to select every records in table using field checkbox for list? Becouse when we select this checkbox, scroll down and new elements appears, they will be unchecked.
Is there a possibility to do something with this checkbox to select every elements without showing them? If yes, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox only selects all listed records, so to check all of them, you first need to scroll to the end of the list and then click on the checkbox.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to check them all without scrolling? Program it?

Comment: I don't think that you can override this behavior on standard list view, maybe on custom one but not sure.